# Calculating confidence intervals for prevalence differences

Tags: confidence-interval, epidemiology

I would like to calculate the confidence intervals for prevalence differences.  If I have the CIs for the prevalence, can I simply subtract the upper limit of one Ci from the upper limit of the other, and do the same for the lower limits as well?  Or is calculating the CIs more complicated than this?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. If the two groups are independent, then read this link http://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/06d2pop.html